# Can't create new user (using the JWT Grant flow and scopes that mentioned in API overview)

Tags: docusignapi

I have a problem with creating another user by Admin API. I don't have an organization_id property in /userinfo response. I need it to create new users via my app. There I also use recommended scopes.

This response I have after call /userinfo

```
{
    "sub": "xxx",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "given_name": "Name",
    "family_name": "Name",
    "created": "2022-02-02T16:38:29.457",
    "email": "some.email@gmail.com",
    "accounts": [
        {
            "account_id": "xxx",
            "is_default": true,
            "account_name": "Name",
            "base_uri": "https://demo.docusign.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also when I used Quickstart App I faced the same problem. I can't create users via this app. Because an organization_id property is missed.
[Quickstart App error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Xoy.png)

Thanks.

#docusignapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Admin API you have to have an organization for your account.

Once you create an organization - you will have an `organizationId` which is used for this API call.

[How to create an organization for your DocuSign account](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-create-org).